# Undo everything git did by using git pull command

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-pull

I had a previous project code and I started using git in between but due to some reasons I need to get back the code that was before I added git. What I did is as follows.

I ran git init command than I ran git remote add origin  command than I ran git pull  command which updated all files I think although files were same.

I need to get back files without updation. I started getting 500 error after I ran git pull command.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

git pull = git fetch + git merge

Technically you have to undo the merge. (undoing fetch will not make sense anyways)

Get the details of which state you want to undo by git reflog

```
$ git reflog
```

Then do a hard reset

```
$ git reset --hard <sha1>
```

First 7 alphanumeric in the sha1 from the reflog will do the job

I hope this will undo your pull. Thanks

Comment: This "0c69558 HEAD@{3}: initial pull" is the initial pull. I want to get back the code before this

Comment: Please share a snapshot of the result with the git reflog in your question